# Routing in lazy loaded module always reloads root component

Tags: angular, routes

I'm running into an issue where navigating to a child route in a lazy-loaded module results in the child's parent route's component reloading.

Here is my main router config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'e',
    loadChildren: () => import('../event/event.module').then(mod => mod.Event_Module)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canLoad: [App_User_Resolver],
    loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(mod => mod.Home_Module),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class App_Routing_Module { }
```

Here is the routing  module for path `e`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':eid',
    canActivateChild: [Event_Resolver],
    component: Event_Root_Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'r/:rid',
        component: Event_Room_Component,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: Event_Default_Component,
      },
    ],
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Event_Routing_Module { }
```

The `Event_Root_Component` contains a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for its child routes.

If I navigate while inside the `e/:eid` route, such as `[routerLink]="['./r', <some_id>]"`, the `Event_Root_Component` will reload under certain circumstances.

The specific case I am referring to is that I get to `e/:eid` by navigating from a route in the `home` module (which is actually a route inside another lazy loaded module inside `home` module). The navigation then takes me to `e/:eid`. Then, when navigating within `e/:eid`, the problem manifests itself (i.e. any subsequent navigations reloads the `Event_Root_Component`). However, if I simply refresh while at `e/:eid` then navigate, the root component will not reload as before.

What can I do prevent the `Event_Root_Component` from reloading?

Comment: Does your 'Event_Resolver' returns true when you try to navigate to the child route? Could you add the code for 'Event_resolver' as well?

Comment: @RahulSingh yes it's returning `true` in all cases.